# Paypal integration in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3

Tags: paypal, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I've been trying to implement a paypal simple payment using PayPal SDK Cordova/Phonegap Plugin into an app with not much luck.

Are there any alternatives to integrate paypal on MobileFirst 6.3? I'm aware that on 7.1 it's enabled to install plugins but my production line can't upgrade for this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to try integrating your Cordova plug-in in the following manner, otherwise you will need to re-consider using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1's Cordova application type, where this will be easily possible.

See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/